# SHA256 HMAC Request Doesn't Validate - Shopify OAuth

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify

I'm having trouble validating the HMAC signature during Shopify OAuth.

When the merchant clicks "install", they are sent to my oauth URL. The url has params added to it like so:

```
https:my-appp.com/shopify_oauth?hmac=74dac492e0605a9d547e8e1e58a287a7748ce8e2679c40b8953d72691c3314c9&host=ZGdoYmpkZnNnYmpoLm15c2hvcGlmeS5jb20vYWRtaW4&shop=merchants_store.myshopify.com&timestamp=1654472682
```

As per the [documentation](https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth/getting-started#step-3-ask-for-permission)

I strip out the HMAC, rebuild the query string with all other params in alphabetical order. Then I run it through a SHA-256 hash function including my apps secret api key.

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
                  , text = `host=${properties.keyvalues[0].value}&shop=${properties.thing1}&timestamp=${properties.thing2}`
                  , key = 'PRIVATE_API_KEY'
                  , hash;

var returnValue

var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(text).digest('hex');

//var base64 = Buffer.from(hash).toString('base64');

if (hash === shopifyHmac) {
returnValue = "true"

} else {
returnValue = "false"
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the provided HMAC does not match the decoded querystring meaning it fails validation.

I've played around with the order of the URL params, as well as which params are included in the querystring. I've also tried encoding it as a base64 format.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the Shopify App code that does work? Or any of the other repos out there in JS that do work? You can bootstrap yourself to a working App pretty quick by not re-inventing the wheel and just borrowed working code.

Comment: Turns out the text string was just referencing the wrong variables and the above code works properly. I need to start taking more breaks when coding haha